# Take result with max count using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, max

I have a data table in memory that looks something like this:

```
Tape               Mask                Count
BT1                DML69               3452
BT2                DML69               1569
BT2                DML87               2745
BT3                DML69               3215
BT3                DML87               1542
BT4                DML87               3214
BT5                DML69               2132
BT5                DML87               1241
```

I need a LINQ query that will return a data row for each tape, one result for each tape, including only the mask with the maximum count. i.e.

```
Tape               Mask                Count
BT1                DML69               3452
BT2                DML87               2745
BT3                DML69               3215
BT4                DML87               3214
BT5                DML69               2132
```

I have tried doing this several different ways, all with no success.  Here is my latest attempt:

```
        foreach (string tape in singOne.GetDistinctTapes(
                                    converter.ConvertProcessesIDToSingOneID(selectedWafer)))
        {
            var tapeMaskQuery =
                from row in tempTable.AsEnumerable()
                where row.Field<string>("location1") == tape
                select row;

            if (tapeMaskQuery.Count() == 1)
            {
                tapeMaskCountTable.Rows.Add(tapeMaskQuery.ElementAt(0));
            }
            else
            {
                var maxMaskQuery =
                    (from fields in tapeMaskQuery.AsEnumerable()
                    select new
                    {
                        tape = fields.Field<string>("location1"),
                        mask = fields.Field<string>("mask"),
                        count = fields.Field<Int64>("count(*)")
                    }).Max(x => x.count);
                tapeMaskCountTable.Rows.Add(maxMaskQuery);
            }
        }
```

Here the singOne.GetDistinctTapes() simply returns a list of distinct tapes on the wafer.  tempTable is a DataTable that is in the form of the first table in this post.  I check to see if the there are more than one result for each tape; if there is, then I run the "maxMaskQuery", which only seems to return a DataRow including just the count column, not the tape and mask column.  I need all three columns to be present in the end, just like in the second table in this post.

Any help on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Kyle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) should let you do this e.g.

```
var query = tapesTable.GroupBy(x => x.Tape)
                      .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(t => t.Count)
                                    .First());
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot; it works perfectly and it's pretty sweet, simple and to the point.  Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Tape)
                 .Select(g => {
                               var maxItem = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                                              .FirstOrDefault();
                               return new { 
                                    Tape = x.Key, 
                                    maxItem.Mask, 
                                    maxItem.Count 
                                  }
                              });
```

Comment: Tape=x.Key should be Tape=g.Key, x doesn't exist at that context,

Answer (score 0):

Just answering the first sentence, use `GroupBy` + `OrderByDescending` and `First`:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> tapeMaskQuery = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Tape"))
    .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<int>("Count"))
                          .First());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the mask with the maximum count, you can write it like this :

```
var maxMaskQuery =
                (from fields in tapeMaskQuery.AsEnumerable()
                select new
                {
                    tape = fields.Field<string>("location1"),
                    mask = fields.Field<string>("mask"),
                    count = fields.Field<Int64>("count(*)")
                }).OrderByDescending(x => x.count).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  var AllSalesForThisMonth = db.Salestable.ToList(); // list the data from the table
    
    var Groupthesale = AllSalesForThisMonth.GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId).ToList();// group them with something unique
                    
 if(Groupthesale!=null)
 {
    var thelargestcountfromthegroup = Groupthesale.OrderBy(c=>c.Count()).Last();// final 
     result
 }
```